# Changing Properties for one data source changes properties for other as well on Datagrip

Tags: amazon-redshift, datagrip

I am trying to connect to one test and one prod environment and I am creating two redshift connections on Datagrip. But as soon as I change properties on one data source, it changes the SSH/SSL tunnel option on the other connection as well. Does anyone know why is this happening and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use seperate SSH configurations here, in the data source properties.

[image]